# how to change the title and icon in react app?

Tags: reactjs, icons, titlebar

I am making a react app. But in the title bar, it is showing 'React App' with React logo. I want to change it to my website name and logo, and how can I do that ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you want to change the title, you can go to: `public/index.html`, and then change the `<title>React App </title>`

To change your logo, go to the public folder and change the `favicon.ico`.

If you follow these steps, your logo and title will get changed.

If it helps you, please mark as accepted answer.

Answer (score 13):

you can change title and icon on `public/index.html` in react project.

```
<head>
    ...
    ...
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <title>React App</title>
    ...
    ...
</head>
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Making changes in `public/index.html` would only change the default values (title and favicon), and it will be set for all pages. More on this method and some (complex) alternatives in the official docs: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/title-and-meta-tags/

...or you can use React Helmet, a third-party library recommended in the official docs as well: https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet. It will allow you to set page title/favicon/other `head` elements from the components itself.

Example code using React Helmet:

```
import {Helmet} from "react-helmet";

class Application extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
        <div className="application">
            <Helmet>
                <meta charSet="utf-8" />
                <title>My Title</title>
                <link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/example" />
            </Helmet>
            ...
        </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: ok, but it's not like I want different logos for other pages . I am ok with changing in index.html as it was simple,

Answer (score 2):

You can change your page title by doing something like this.

```
 const pageTitle = `${title}`;
```

Then:

```
 document.title = pageTitle;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change the logo from ./assets/index.htm and change the href.

and input your image to ./assets/

Comment: Your answer is not very specific. Adding a code snippet or describing individual steps in greater detail would help!

Answer (score 0):

To change page `Title` and `Icon` of the page use following steps

1. Inside your projects public folder open `index.html`
2. Update the title to your project name `<title>Project Name</title>`
3. To change icon
4. Duplicate and rename your app logo to `favicon.ico` and replace in public folder
5. Replace your `logos.png` to your logos
6. Save and reload the application

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue. I have build a generic website and the URL to the favicon is also stored in the DB. So no chance to set it already in the HTML file.

```js
function App(): React.JSX.Element {
  const [config, setConfig] = useState<types.ProjectConfig | null>(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    getProjectConfig().then((config: types.ProjectConfig) => {
      const favicon = document.querySelector("link[rel~='icon']") as HTMLLinkElement
      if (favicon) {
        favicon.href = config.faviconURL // In your case just replace this with the URL in string format
      }
      document.title = config.pageTitle
      setConfig(config)
    })
  }, [])
```

This works for me :)